# display oldest value with newest value at id level

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks something like this where ids are displayed with old value with the new value (the one it just got changed into).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#TT','U')IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #TT;

SELECT *
INTO #TT
FROM (
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'A' AS OldValue, 'B' AS NewValue, CONVERT(DATE,'20190421') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 1 AS ID, 'B' AS OldValue, 'C' AS NewValue, CONVERT(DATE,'20190423') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS ID, 'D' AS OldValue, 'E' AS NewValue, CONVERT(DATE,'20190422') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 'J' AS OldValue, 'K' AS NewValue, CONVERT(DATE,'20190422') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 'K' AS OldValue, 'L' AS NewValue, CONVERT(DATE,'20190423') AS [Date]
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 AS ID, 'L' AS OldValue, 'M' AS NewValue, CONVERT(DATE,'20190424') AS [Date]
) T
;
```

I want to display each id and old value with newest value available for them. For example ID=1 and OldValue = A should display C or ID = 3 and OldValue = K should display M

I have tried to do recursive cte as follows:

```
WITH RecCTE AS (
SELECT ID, OldValue, NewValue
FROM #TT
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ID, B.OldValue, A.NewValue
FROM #TT A
INNER JOIN RecCTE B ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.NewValue = A.OldValue
)

SELECT *
FROM RecCTE
```

With that recursive query. I am getting some line correctly but I am also getting extra lines in between:

```
|       ID  |   OldValue    |    NewValue    |
|-----------|---------------|----------------|
|       1   |      A        |       B        |
|       1   |      B        |       C        |
|       2   |      D        |       E        |
|       3   |      J        |       K        |
|       3   |      K        |       L        |
|       3   |      L        |       M        |
|       3   |      K        |       M        |
|       3   |      J        |       L        |
|       3   |      J        |       M        |
|       1   |      A        |       C        |
```

I want to get results like this:

```
    |       ID  |   OldValue    |    NewValue    |
    |-----------|---------------|----------------|
    |       1   |      A        |       C        |
    |       1   |      B        |       C        |
    |       2   |      D        |       E        |
    |       3   |      J        |       M        |
    |       3   |      K        |       M        |
    |       3   |      L        |       M        |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think taking the last row should work:

```
WITH RecCTE AS (
      SELECT ID, OldValue, NewValue, 1 as lev
      FROM #TT
      UNION ALL
      SELECT A.ID, B.OldValue, A.NewValue, lev + 1
      FROM #TT A JOIN
           RecCTE B
           ON A.ID = B.ID AND B.NewValue = A.OldValue
     )
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT r.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id, OldValue ORDER BY lev DESC) as seqnum
      FROM RecCTE r
     ) r
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data works the way it looks to me like it works, the following will do it without using recursion:

```
;WITH cte as (
   --  List of all, ordered by ID, with the most recent being the first listed
   SELECT
       ID
      ,NewValue
      ,row_number() over (partition by Id order by Date desc)  Ranking
     from #TT
    )
select
   tt.Id
  ,tt.OldValue
  ,cte.NewValue
 from #TT  tt
  --  Join table to the "most recent" row for the ID
  inner join cte
   on cte.ID = tt.Id
    and cte.Ranking = 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Simple solution.Ranking them did not even come to my mind.

Comment: @blitzboxer . . . This will not walk multiple steps through the data, so I don't think it solves your general problem.

Comment: The problem described was "I want to display each id and old value with newest value available for them." They took the approach of using recursion to solve it. Reviewing the data disclosed a means of resolving the original problem without using recursion.

Comment: I think Gordon is right. lets say there are more records. for example for it has ID=1, OldValue=X, NewValue='Y' and another with ID=1, OldValue=Y and NewValue=Z. I think ranking by date might cause problem it will either pick C or Z depending on most recent date. Gordon is correct on using levels in recursive cte and order them by levels. Thank you for pointing it out, Gordon. Philip did get the part right for given data but generally Gordon's response is better suited.

Comment: If the real problem is defined by the hierarchical chain, and not by the date (as is indicated by the terms "old" and "new"), then yes, this is correct.